# How to sync local keychain to device and iCloud in Xamarin iOS

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios

For my application, when a user login, I display a prompt and ask if the user wants to save the password to keychain. The code saves successfully and I'm able to query the keychain for the stored password completely fine.

My question is how come when I check my phone under Passwords & Acccounts - Website & App Passwords, nothing is displayed.

[image]

The bit of code I used to save the key

```
public static bool SaveValueToKeyChain(string entryKey, string entryValue)
{
    SecRecord record = new SecRecord(SecKind.GenericPassword)
    {
        Account = entryKey,
        Label = entryKey,
        Service = _keyChainServiceName
    };

    SecStatusCode resultCode;
    SecKeyChain.QueryAsRecord(record, out resultCode);

    if (resultCode == SecStatusCode.Success)
    {
        if (SecKeyChain.Remove(record) != SecStatusCode.Success)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    resultCode = SecKeyChain.Add(new SecRecord(SecKind.GenericPassword)
    {
        Label = entryKey,
        Account = entryKey,
        Service = _keyChainServiceName,
        Accessible = SecAccessible.WhenUnlockedThisDeviceOnly,
        Synchronizable = true,
        ValueData = NSData.FromString(entryValue, NSStringEncoding.UTF8),

    });


    return resultCode == SecStatusCode.Success;
}
```

I've also followed the solution from here https://developer.xamarin.com/samples/monotouch/Keychain/ and no luck as well. May I get some assistance.

Answer (score 0):

For each application, the keychain has two access zones, a **private** zone and a **public** zone (that is, a group mode).

**Private area** ：is a closed storage area. Each application can only operate its own private area. Any data stored in this application is invisible to other programs, and other programs do not have permission to access this private area. (Can be understood as a sandbox with a keychain).

**Public area**: apple provides a data sharing module between multiple apps developed by the same developer account. It is now limited to data sharing between different apps under the same developer account. This area is another data storage space that is independent of the private area. Achieve common access to some data between multiple applications.

I guess here should be the private area.You can have a try with group mode. [Sharing Access to Keychain Items Among a Collection of Apps](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/keychain_services/keychain_items/sharing_access_to_keychain_items_among_a_collection_of_apps)

Comment: If I was able to achieve public area, would it appear under website & App passwords?

Comment: @Phoenix Do you need it also appear in website & App ?

Comment: Jiang, yes I do.

Comment: @Phoenix Okey, this just can be shared between app .

Comment: so how does the starbucks app do it? They have a prompt asking if you'd like to save password to keychain and it saves under website & App passwords

Comment: Browser's website maybe has web api to do,however here is mobile app , so this just works for app .If using webview in app , using javascript can related to app , finally will be the same as using app's function.